# Comparison with NULL behavior the same even when setting ANSI_NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Some_Column (Table ABC)
___
123    
456    
NULL   
789
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM ABC` it returns all rows.
However, when I run

`SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE Some_Column <> ''`

it returns all the values but the null. Whether `ANSI_NULLS` is on or off.

Can anyone explain this peculiar behavior to me?

Comment: Applies to SQL 2015 and up: In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by design.  From [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=sql.100).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the column. Also, **a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not NULL.**

So, `WHERE Some_Column <> ''` returns all rows that are not `''` and are not NULL.

This query with ANSI_NULLS OFF:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC 
WHERE Some_Column <> '';
```

Is equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC 
WHERE Some_Column <> ''
    AND Some_Column IS NOT NULL;
```

When ANSI_NULLS is ON, of course, then normal ANSI [Three Valued Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) applies.  NULL is never equal to anything, including NULL.  NULL is also never *not* equal to anything, including NULL.

Either way, you should expect to use `Some_Column IS NOT NULL` or `Some_Column IS NULL` and explicitly handle NULL values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC 
WHERE Some_Column <> ''
    OR Some_Column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because NULL is neither equal to, nor unequal to ''...NULL is simply the absence of a value.  You could claim it is 'unknown'.

The only way of including NULLs in the return of your query is to add a clause to check for null values:-

```
SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE Some_Column <> '' OR Some_Column IS NOT NULL
```

ANSI_NULLS won't alter this behaviour. It only allows you to carry out direct comparisons to null as a 'value' e.g.

```
WHERE Some_Column = NULL
```

Rather than

```
WHERE Some_Column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply observing documented behavior: [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

1. If `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`, then the following rule applies:

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN

In other words, `NULL <> ''` evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, not `TRUE`, so the row is not returned.

---

2. In the case of `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, then the doc is also very clear about that:

> a SELECT statement that uses ***WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows*** that are not XYZ_value and ***that are not NULL***.

---

If you want to observe the difference in behavior between `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` and `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`, try your test using the condition `WHERE Some_Column = NULL`.